# Unable to detect multiple exposed type in Power BI Custom Connector Power Query/M

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

I am trying to expose multiple functions in the PowerBI UI.  I could never find any of them if more than 1 function is exposed.  I am writing this using the VS Code Power Query SDK. Is this a bug within the SDK?

```
[DataSource.Kind="myAPI", Publish="Publish1"]
shared myFunc1 = Value.ReplaceType(myFunc1Get, myFunc1Params);
[DataSource.Kind="myAPI", Publish="Publish2"]
shared myFunc2 = Value.ReplaceType(myFunc2Get, myFunc2Params);

myAPI = [
    Authentication = [
        Key = []
    ],
    Label = "My Kind"
];
Publish1 = [
  ...
]

Publish2 = [
  ...
]
```